# I am getting an error when I want to get input

Tags: c#, input

Here is my code

```
using System;

namespace Test
{
    class Main
    {
        public static void MainVoid(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter x: ");
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(x + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

Compiler throws an error

> Entry method 'Main' in class 'Program' in namespace 'Rextester' not found

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every program there should be a `Main` function which is entry point. You cannot change the name of that function to `MainVoid`.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world!");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler compiles your program, it searches for the entry point of your program. In C#, per language definition, this is a static void called "Main". For further information [see the Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio) on getting started with C#.

Since your program has no method called `Main` that is static, the compiler is is giving you this error since the compiler is expecting your program to have a main method.

In your case, the correct program would be:

```
using System;

namespace Rextester
{
    class MainProgram
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter x: ");
            string x = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write(x + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but it gave me another error -> (7:28) 'Main': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type

Comment: Oh yes forgot about that. When you have a class called "X" and specify a member (such as a property or a function in this case) the compiler gets confused. The only thing in a class that can be named like the class is/are the constructors of said class. Renaming your class to anything else (eg "MainClass") should resolve this issue.